# Detecting Socket disconnect

Tags: java, sockets, disconnection

I've a Socket connected to another device on my LAN. How can i detect the disconnection When i unplug the device from the AC. The thread is blocked on:

```
BufferedReader b=//
b.readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use such logic, then set a timeout on the socket (i.e. [`setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)). This will interrupt the blocking I/O operation.